# Using an exponentiation function

Tags: functional-programming, coq, theorem-proving

This is the definition for `exp` in group theory:

```
Definition exp : Z -> U -> U.
Proof.
intros n a.
elim n;
 clear n.
exact e.
intro n.
 elim n; clear n.
exact a.
intros n valrec.
exact (star a valrec).
intro n; elim n; clear n.
exact (inv a).
intros n valrec.
exact (star (inv a) valrec).
Defined.
```

I tried to define a ((a^n)^k) this way.

```
Definition exp2 (n k : Z) (a : U)  := fun a => exp k (exp  n a).
```

But `exp k (exp n a)` is of type `U->U` but I want it to be of type `U`. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Defining a function through tactics is unreadable. What are `Z` and `U`? Please post complete code.

Comment: Your definition of `exp2` has an obvious mistake: you're declaring two arguments called `a`. Make that `exp2 (n k : Z) (a : U)  := exp …` or `exp2 (n k : Z) := fun a => exp …`

Answer (score 1):

As Gilles pointed out, the signature of your `exp2` function is equivalent to

```
Definition exp2 (n k : Z) (a a(*won't work in Coq*) : U) :=
    exp k (exp n a).
```

You need to remove one of the `a`:

```
Definition exp2 (n k : Z) (a : U) := exp k (exp n a).
Definition exp2_alt (n k : Z) : fun a => exp k (exp n a).
```